# Returning multiple groups of data in a JSON ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

If I wanted to make one request, but return multiple groups of responses, how would I separate them to be able to parse them in jQuery and get the `.length` as well of each group?

First Group (A)

```
[
   {"name":"Tu\u011Frul","surname":"Topuz","message":"Hello World"}
   ,{"name":"Tu\u011Frul","surname":"Topuz","message":"Hello World"}
]
```

Second Group (B)

```
[
   {"name":"Tu\u011Frul","surname":"Topuz","message":"Hello World"}
   ,{"name":"Tu\u011Frul","surname":"Topuz","message":"Hello World"}
]
```

Total Response (Single request):

```
[
   {"name":"Tu\u011Frul","surname":"Topuz","message":"Hello World"}
   ,{"name":"Tu\u011Frul","surname":"Topuz","message":"Hello World"}
]
,[
   {"name":"Tu\u011Frul","surname":"Topuz","message":"Hello World"}
   ,{"name":"Tu\u011Frul","surname":"Topuz","message":"Hello World"}
]
```

Or would I return it in another way to properly do this?  Or would I have to do them separately, I prefer to keep it in one response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make them into an array, or an object with each group as an element in the array or object

object

```
{
  "groupa":[
   {"name":"Tu\u011Frul","surname":"Topuz SR","message":"Hello World"},
   {"name":"Tu\u011Frul","surname":"Topuz","message":"Hello World"}
    ],
  "groupb":[
    {"name":"Tu\u011Frul","surname":"Topuz","message":"Hello World"},
    {"name":"Tu\u011Frul","surname":"Topuz JR","message":"Hello World"}
]}

success(data){
    data["groupa"].length//number of items in group a
    data["groupa"][0]["surname"] == "Topuz SR"//true;
    data["groupb"][1]["surname"] == "Topuz JR"//true;
}
```

array

```
[[
   {"name":"Tu\u011Frul","surname":"Topuz","message":"Hello World"},
   {"name":"Tu\u011Frul","surname":"Topuz","message":"Hello World"}
    ],
  [
    {"name":"Tu\u011Frul","surname":"Topuz","message":"Hello World"},
    {"name":"Tu\u011Frul","surname":"Topuz","message":"Hello World"}
]]


success(data){
    data[0].length//number of items in first group
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how about grabbing a value from group a?